# 2 methods with the same name in python

Tags: python

In Python, could I write 2 methods having the same name but different number of parameters ?

```
em.on_create_experience(action.dest_id)
em.on_create_experience2(action.dest_id,0)
```

Comment: you *can*, but you need something to *handle* those parameters, should they encounter them

Answer (score 1):

You can't write two separate methods with different parameter lists. But you can write one method with optional keyword parameters to do what you want.